# How to debug DriveApp.getFileById with Google App script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm not able to return a file that I know is in my Google Drive and I'm unsure how to debug what the issue is.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
function get_file_contents() {
  try {
    var fileName = "rainbows.json";
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName)

     if (files.hasNext()) {
       var file = files.next();
       var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
       var json = JSON.parse(content);
     }
  }catch(e){log(e)}
  return json;
}
```

When I use the debugger in google app script it hangs for a while on the `var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName)` line and then stops. All I'm getting back is `{}`.

Besides this, I've tried using `DriveApp.getFileById()` and I get the same result.

If you could point me to any resources for this I'd appreciate it. I've already tried looking through the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename), but I am either missing something or the answer's not in there.

Comment: You should log `e.message` not `e`

Comment: Could it be that the file is in the Bin or in a Shared Drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can't debug the internal behaviour of calls to services like DriveApp, you can only look at what you pass to it, and what it returns.

If you aren't able to find a given file by name, the issue is likely higher level, such as with permissions or the file location.

[DriveApp.getFilesByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFilesByName(String)) "Gets a collection of all files **in the user's Drive** that have the given name." The part I've bolded is key, it does not not pickup files that you have access too, but are not in your Drive. For example, files that are shared with you, or files that are on shared drives.

However DriveApp.getFileById() should work in both those cases, fetching any file you have access too.

I would zero in on testing with DriveApp.getFileById(), note that getFileById returns a [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) object, rather than a [File Iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator), so you can't just drop it in place of getFilesByName(). It needs to be tested differently.  getFileById() should raise an exception on failure, while getFilesByName() just returns an empty iterator.

If you can't open the file by ID, you are likely looking at a permissions issue, perhaps the script is running under the wrong account, or hasn't been granted access to Drive (although you should be prompted to grant this scope automatically), or is running from a trigger that doesn't allow DriveApp access.